# Pipe between sockets

Tags: c++, c, sockets, copy, pipe

I've got a C++ server that acts as a mirror. What gets in gets out to a different socket. Right now, it reads the socket into a buffer and writes it into the other socket. I want to improve the throughput.

I've [read stuff](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html#zerocopy) about `sendfile()` and `splice()`, but it seems limited to "file-to-socket" transfers. Maybe a simple `pipe()` between sockets would work. What do you recommend?

A portable solution would be perfect, but it's fine if it's Linux-only.

Comment: This might be of some use http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9593/can-splice-tee-be-made-to-work-with-sockets-and-not-merely-pipes

Comment: May be you can use same port for both sockets !

Comment: One more link which does transferring data through pipe :) : http://markmail.org/thread/4cils4zyoxtrq3zu

Comment: what about just #nc -l listen_port > destination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup a named pipe in linux.  Multiple processes could read/write from this.  Check out this link: http://www.cs.fredonia.edu/zubairi/s2k2/csit431/more_pipes.html.

Also as mentioned above using netcat should do the trick (http://netcat.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: As far as I know (according to a BSD source file), `nc` uses a buffer of 8192 bytes, which is basically my solution at the moment.

Comment: I might consider using a named pipe and benchmark it, but even if the FIFO file is RAM-based, I can't see how it might go faster than a simple memory copy.

Answer (score 1):

I checked `nc(netcat)` command as mentioned by `Ralu` in his comment and  it works between two sockets when used with pipe :)

I used the below command :

```
netcat -l 5556 | netcat localhost 5557
```

I sent data to the port 5556(a python client) set up by the first nc command and made a server(small python code) listening on port 5557.

I could recv data from port 5557

Comment: Certainly, but the question is not about the possibility of doing it, it's about _optimizing it_.