# Make a bridge between 2 TCP sockets with BOOST

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I use BOOST c++ library in a little 'go between' program to link two TCP sockets:

S1 call the server

S2 call the server

If everything is fine, the server "link" S1 and S2: all data arriving by S1 are sended to S2, and all data arriving by S2 are sended to S1
I close the 2 sockets if there is an EOF or an error.

Actually, I use BOOST async_read_some and async_write, and it works fine, but I find this pretty ugly...

So I want to ask if there is a more 'basic' way to achieve this, for example with streams.

Comment: You should check named pipes. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697617/pipe-between-sockets/7698068) is a question that may be similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I use boost::asio with gcc
And my program run on a Window machine.